# Minimum directory structure and ant build file contents for Java web app

Tags: java, ant, wicket

What is the minimal conventional directory structure for a Java web app? What do I need to put in a `build.xml` file to get ant to build it and make a WAR file?

My goal is to deploy a Wicket app to Tomcat without using an IDE. I want to do it with only ant and my favourite text editor.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe not the most minimalist possible, but the Tomcat project has an [Application Developer's Guide](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/index.html) with a [section on source layout](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/source.html) and a [sample build.xml](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/build.xml.txt)

Also, if you are starting a new project, you might want to check out Maven. With Maven, rather than crafting your own build scripts, you adhere to standard layout to do stuff, and then Maven figures out all the rest. It also manages dependencies, including its own. Learning curve is a bit steep, though.

Comment: I'd vote up on the advice to refer to the Tomcat app dev guide. But a vote down for using maven :P

Answer (score 2):

Ours look like this:

```
web/
web/WEB-INF/   (sometimes we use a conf/ dir at the top level but this is minimal)
src/
lib/
```

The build.xml has three targets:

- jsp: copies everything from web/ into the tomcat webapp folder and from lib/ into WEB-INF/lib
- compile: compiles everything from src/ into WEB-INF/classes in the webapp
- war: runs compile, jsp, and then zips the contents of the tomcat webapp into a warfile

This structure is a little bit informal and you can do it more cleanly by having a separate build directory for the warfile, and/or a separate compile directory, etc. Some people don't like the idea of deploying directly to the webapp instead of building a war first. But to get something up and running quickly, the above will do nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out maven. It's really complicated, but to build a war file it's simple, and there are plugins that will deploy the war to tomcat.

Comment: It's not _that_ complicated. :)

Comment: Maybe complicated was the wrong word. There's just a learning curve that must be overcome right at first. I've been using it for years and it's easy now.